# Add Specific Multiple Dates To Caldendar

Tags: android

I'm using this calendar library: https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View
I'm trying to add multiple specific dates to calendar.

I'm using the following code so far:

```
    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

    List<EventDay> events = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    events.add(new EventDay(cal1, R.drawable.icon));

    calendarView.setEvents(events);
```

The above adds and sets an icon to 1 day after today on the calendar.

I would like to add specific dates as an example like so:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrDate = new ArrayList<>();
    arrDate.add("2022-08-01");
    arrDate.add("2022-08-02");
    arrDate.add("2022-08-06");
    arrDate.add("2022-08-07");

     for (String s_date : arrDate){
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(s_date);
    }
```

I can extract and convert string (s_date) "yyyy-mm-dd" to calendar format: year, month, day but right now I just want to understand how I can add multiple specific dates from my array of dates.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I'll share full code to assist others:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View
Calendar cal;
CalendarView calendarView;
List<EventDay> events;
int calYear, calMonth, calDay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> arrDate = new ArrayList<>();
    arrDate.add("2022-08-01");
    arrDate.add("2022-08-02");
    arrDate.add("2022-08-06");
    arrDate.add("2022-08-07");

    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

    events = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s_date : arrDate){
        convertStringDateToCalendarDate(s_date);
        setCalendarIcons();
    }
}

private void setCalendarIcons() {

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, calYear);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, calMonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calDay);

    events.add(new EventDay(cal, R.drawable.icon));
    calendarView.setEvents(events);
}

private void convertStringDateToCalendarDate(String s_date) {

    String[] parts = s_date.split("-");
    String first = parts[0];
    String second = parts[1];
    String third = parts[2];

    calYear = Integer.parseInt(first);
    calMonth = Integer.parseInt(second)-1;      //-1 Month starts at 0 (Jan)
    calDay = Integer.parseInt(third);
}
```

}